# さらっと滑り meaning and use in this sentence

Tags: translation

無理難題さらっと滑り込ませるのやめてくだい.

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence, someone is asking the permission to stop doing something because it's impossible to (?)

Could you please explain me? Thank you.

Comment: Does it really say 之?

Comment: It seems like it, it's handwritten so unfortunately I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe it says 滑り込ませる?  Can you show a picture of the handwriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

無理難題さらっと滑り之ませるのやめてくだい makes no sense as is because of the 之 character.

If it were 込 or こ, it would make perfect sense and the sentence would mean:

"Please do not slip a tall order in here as if it were nothing!" if that makes sense in English.  In case it does not, the speaker is asking this person not to make an unreasonable demand without hesitation.

Comment: I understand now, looking better at it the right kanji is this 込 that's why the whole sentence was weird! Thank you very much.